# Ubuntu 18.04 Evince and Calibre reader must be restarted every page to load font

Tags: 18.04, fonts, pdf, evince, calibre

For PDF files about 15 MB or more, the fonts are garbled every time I go to a new page.

If I close the file and reopen it, the font on the current page is fine, but other pages are garbled. It happens to both Evince and Calibre. Is there a way to fix this?

I haven't tried with other readers yet.

PDF file:
[image: PDF file]

`pdffonts` result:

```
Internal Error: xref num 0 not found but needed, try to reconstruct<0a>
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
ABAKIB+Roboto-Regular                Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no  [none]
POMGON+EconSansOSMed                 Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no  [none]
POMGOO+EconSansOSXBol                Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no  [none]
POMGPP+MiloTE-Bold                   Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no  [none]
PONDCO+EconSansMed                   Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no  [none]
PONDCP+EcoPict-Two                   Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no  [none]
PONDDA+EconSansBol                   Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no  [none]
PONDDB+EconSansBolOS                 Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no  [none]
PONDFB+MiloTE-Text                   Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no  [none]
PONDFC+MiloTE-Bold                   Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no  [none]
PONDGD+MiloTE-TextIta                Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no  [none]
PONDGE+EconSansMedItaOS              Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no  [none]
PONDCN+EconSansRegOS                 Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no  [none]
PONJGE+EconSansCndLig                Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no  [none]
AAPFOB+EconSansMed                   Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no  [none]
```

Comment: I'm not sure that it will help, but you could try to regenerate the font cache file:  `sudo fc-cache -f -v`

Comment: The problem still persists.

Comment: The error message at the output of `pdffonts` seems to indicate a problem with what are called xref tables within the file structure.  My limit understanding is that this can happen occasionally in TeX and LaTeX output, and with a slightly differing file structure between Windows and Linux.  You can try to reconstruct the pdf with a command like `gs   -o <newFileName>.pdf   -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite <originalFileName>.pdf`  This is a non-destructive command, and worth a try.

Comment: @knt5784 Are you still having this problem?  Can you provide a sample PDF for examination?